# Parsing URL with matrix paramers using net/url built-in package

Tags: url, go, httprequest, url-parsing

It seems that [URL](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) does not support [matrix parameters](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html)

```
// From net/url
type URL struct {
        Scheme   string
        Opaque   string    // encoded opaque data
        User     *Userinfo // username and password information
        Host     string    // host or host:port
        Path     string
        RawQuery string // encoded query values, without '?'
        Fragment string // fragment for references, without '#'
}
```

- Why ?
- How can I extract matrix parameters from an URL ? and when should I use them instead of using requests parameters embedded in the `request.URL.RawQuery` part of the URL ?

Comment: From the document you linked: "Note: relative Matrix URLs are notgenerally implemented so this is just a theoretical discussion." I don't think Matrix URLs have ever been declared standard and neither have I seen them in general use. Why should Go implement them?

Comment: @FUZxxl So, no one is using them ?

Comment: They aren't even a thing! The document you linked is an idea for a feature that could've been implemented but it was dropped.

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks, maybe I should delete the question.

Comment: No, there is no need for that. It can stay as a reminder for other people who stumple upon Matrix URI's.

Comment: @FUZxxl feel free to edit any part of it (I'm not a native English speaker)

Answer (score 0):

The parameters end up getting put in `url.Path`. Here's a function which can put them in the `Query` for you:

```
func ParseWithMatrix(u string) (*url.URL, error) {
    parsed, err := url.Parse(u)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if strings.Contains(parsed.Path, ";") {
        q := parsed.Path[strings.Index(parsed.Path, ";")+1:]
        m, err := url.ParseQuery(q)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        for k, vs := range parsed.Query() {
            for _, v := range vs {
                m.Add(k, v)
            }
        }
        parsed.Path = parsed.Path[:strings.Index(parsed.Path, ";")]
        parsed.RawQuery = m.Encode()
    }
    return parsed, nil
}
```